# SVM type in openCV

Tags: opencv, svm

I am using opencv to develop a very simple classifer for image. I want to use svm type poly but it gives error while other like sigmoid, RBF works fine. I defined the parameters as follows:

```
SVMParams params;
params.svm_type = SVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = SVM::POLY;
params.gamma = 20;
params.degree = 0;
params.coef0 = 0;

params.C = 7;
params.nu = 0.0;
params.p = 0.0;

params.class_weights = NULL;
params.term_crit.type = CV_TERMCRIT_ITER +CV_TERMCRIT_EPS;
params.term_crit.max_iter = 1000;
params.term_crit.epsilon = 1e-6;
```

The error reads openCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (The kernel parameter  must be positive) in CvSVM::set_params. I am unsure what is the error about.?

Comment: It's probably `degree`. A degree zero polynomial kernel doesn't make sense, as its value is a constant.

Comment: Which version of OpenCV are you using?

Answer (score 9):

For a polynomial kernel, `degree` must be larger than 1 (0 is invalid, 1 is linear). For most packages, the default value for degree is 3.

RBF and sigmoid kernels work fine with your settings because they don't use `degree`. For reference, the kernel functions in question are:

- polynomial: `k(u,v)=(gamma*u'*v + coef0)^degree`,
- RBF: `k(u,v)=exp(-gamma*|u-v|^2)`,
- sigmoid: `k(u,v)=tanh(gamma*u'*v + coef0)`.